# Have conditional belongs_to and has_one associations for ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say I have a model `A` that can belong to model `B` and model `C`. And model `B` can belong to model `C`.  I want an instance of `A` to refer to `B`'s `C` if `B` is present else refer to it's own `C`.

So I kind of want (for `A`)

```
belongs_to :B, optional: true
belongs_to :C
has_one    :C, through: :B
```

but I want the association of `C` to be dependent on the presence of `B`.  How do I achieve this?

Note: I also want my queries to be efficient for `A`, so `A.all.includes(:C)` should work.

Comment: Is there a possibility, that you will need `A` to have both `B` and `C` associations specified at once?

Comment: @AntonTkachov No, I don't think so.

Comment: I'm unclear as to why you have A both `belongs_to` C and `has_one` C. Can you clarify the hierarchy you would like to achieve?

Comment: It helped a bit. I will share my minds in response

Answer (score 0):

I would go with polymorphic association, so model `A` has either `B` (association_type: 'B' and association_id: ...) or `C` (association_type: 'C' and association_id: ...).

The only one real issue you have after this is how to handle A.includes(:C). We can think about some way to write some custom solution to replace such behaviour. Anyway `includes` will execute additional query.

If you think such approach is useful for you, I will think about some custom solution and share my minds.